# AWS Amplify API error - field is not of type Int

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to push my AWS Amplify API schema/create the resource but it errors out saying:

```
✖ An error occurred when pushing the resources to the cloud

managerId field is not of type Int
```

The error goes away if I change managerId to an Int on the Writer type but I don't want to do that. It should be an ID. Any idea what's wrong here?

**schema.graphql**

```
type Writer implements Person 
  @model
  @searchable
  @key(name: "byManager", fields: ["managerId", "hourlyPay"])
  @auth(rules: [
    {allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"]},
    {allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read]}
  ])
{
  id: ID!
  managerId: ID!
  name: String!
  hourlyPay: Float!
  manager: Manager! @connection(fields: ["managerId"])
}

type Manager implements Person 
  @model
  @searchable
  @auth(rules: [
    {allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"]},
    {allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read]}
  ])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  department: String
  writers: [Writer!]! @connection(keyName: "byManager", fields: ["id"])
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the definition of `Person` interface to see what is defined there

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in an Android project I was working on.

I fixed it by placing the next code in a file I created under `app/src/main/graphql` (I had to create the folder graphql).

**/app/src/main/graphql/aws-directives.graphql**

```
directive @connection(name: String, keyField: String, sortField: String, limit: Int) on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

Then, instead of using @key I only used the directive @connection like this

```
type Comment @model {
   id: ID!
   text: String!
   postId: Post @connection(name: "commentsByPost")
}


type Post @model {
   id: ID!
   comments: [Comment] @connection(name: "commentsByPost")
}
```

Finally when you create comments you have to pass the postId. If you do a query to list the Posts and its comments you will get the comments associated with each post correctly.

Comment: This looks possible like a bug in the Amplify CLI's code generation. Please submit a GitHub issue to https://github.com/aws-amplilfy/amplify-cli.